# MVC view not being generated with validation from the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, validation, model-view-controller

I'm using MVC 5 with EF6 and Database first..
I have two tables, table A and B, both of them with non nullable fields.
I did the same procedure for both of them, create the controller and the view, but for some reason, the html of the view to create records for table B does not generate the client validations.

Table A:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[A](
    [ID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CodA] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Volume] [decimal](15, 2) NOT NULL,
    [CreationDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [A_pk] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)
```

Table B:

```sql
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[B](
    [ID] [smallint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Codigo] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [Iso2] [varchar](2) NOT NULL,
    [Iso3] [varchar](3) NOT NULL,
    [Designation] [nvarchar](128) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [B_pk] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC
)
```

Html for a field in a view to create a record in table A:

```html
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field Volume must be a number." data-val-required="The Volume field is required." id="Volume" name="Volume" type="text" value="">
```

Code from the cshtml create file for table A:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Volume, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Html for a field in a view to create a record in table B:

```html
<input class="form-control text-box single-line" id="Codigo" name="Codigo" type="text" value="">
```

Code from the cshtml create file for table B:

```
@Html.EditorFor(model => model.Iso3, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
```

Controller for the create action for table A

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(A a)
        {
            if(ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.A.Add(a);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Backoffice");
            }

            return View(a);
        }
```

Controller for the create action for table B

```cs
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(B b)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.B.Add(b);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Backoffice");
            }

            return View(b);
        }
```

The controllers are identical.

In table A the view shows the validation message for the not nullable fields while in table B it gets to the controller and throws an exception in the SaveChanges method.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add data validation attribute
    `[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false)]` to your class properties.